# Porque sale este error Input string was not in a correct format en c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Buenos Dias:
La paz con todos...

> Error Buscar en textbox no se controlo FromExcepcion ,Input string was
>   not in a correct format.

el folio es tipo numeric, al buscar en mi textbox si lo hace, pero al quitar todo lo que escribe en el textbox me marca ese error, alguien podría decirme una solución???

```
private void txtBusqueda_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
        if ((txtBusqueda.Text) != null){
            conexSQL.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from _producto where folio=@folio", conexSQL);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@folio",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32 (txtBusqueda.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read()){
                cmbNom.Text = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                cmbDes.Text = dr["descripcion"].ToString();
            }
            else{

            }
            dr.Close();
            conexSQL.Close();
        }
      }
```

Comment: que valor tiene el txtBusqueda.text al momento de hacer la conversión ( Convert.ToInt32 (txtBusqueda.Text);)

Comment: `txtBusqueda.Text.Trim()` quizá la cadena contiene espacios vacios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser que el TextBox no sea nulo en su contenido por lo cual ingrese en el if

lo correcto seria

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBusqueda.Text)){ ...
```

Tambien podrias usar

```
int busqueda = 0;

if(int.TryParse(txtBusqueda.Text, out busqueda)){

    //si ingresa es un valor nro valido

}
```

por supuesto usarias la variable `busqueda` en el parametro de la query

Comment: Muchas Gracias si funciono a la perfeccion, buen dia :)